# Can we get a close reason for "where can I get free resource X"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

"Where can I get free resource X?" style questions are off topic, but when flagging such questions, we don't have an indicator for that reason. Could we get one? If not, then which flag should we select for such things?

Presently the off-topic options are:

- Programming questions that aren't specific to game development
- Questions about "how to get started," "what to learn next," or "which technology to use"
- Questions without a minimal, complete, verifiable example of the issue
- Blatantly off-topic with nothing to do with game development

None of these seem like a clean fit for "find me free X." @DH mentioned, option 2 links to the help center & this is probably more of a first timer type requst - maybe that option could be tweaked to include this issue as an example to help guide the less experienced (both the OPs & the mods). Thoughts?

Comment: I usually pick the second option because it links to the help center, where it clearly says that asking for free resources is off-topic.

Comment: Smart; didn't know that it links to help center. Perhaps that option could be edited to include "find me free X" as an example.

Comment: We can *change* the text of the 'which technology' close reason, but it has to fit in the character limit and I believe the current wording is basically exactly on that limit. A proposal to change it would need to account for that. I would further move that 'free' is irrelevant to the issue.

Answer (score 3):

We get three custom close reasons, and we're using all three currently. In extreme circumstances sites have been granted a 4th, but I don't think we see nearly enough of the "finding resources" questions to justify StackExchange giving us an extra slot.

The questions covered by our existing close reasons are far more common, especially since the generic "too broad" close reason covers these "finding resources" questions fairly well. "Too broad" is usually what I use to close them, the custom "which technology" close reason is also good and covers the topic.

Further, in the past these questions were on-topic and there are several floating around in the sites history. They are closed now, but in the interest of getting askers as much help as is possible, duplicate questions should be linked to them where possible instead of closing outright.

Comment: Didn't know there was a custom close reason limit. I agree this probably doesn't warrant one if these are used so sparingly. Editing & staying within the char limit seems unlikely. Aside from missing a chance to link to a duplicate, does it create any problems if there flag reasons for this aren't consistent?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter, the flags are mainly to bring the question to the attention of users who can vote-to-close (or not).